# Trouble with Google Map API

Tags: api, dictionary

I am having trouble with getting the Google Map API to function properly. I am getting and error that says "This page can't load Google Maps correctly." I believe my key is set up correctly and I believe the code is correct. I think I need a fresh pair of eyes to correct the issue(s). Any help would be appreciated. The webpage is https://bplsv.com/contact.html
Thank you!

```
<section class="cd-section">
<div class="cd-block">
<div class="contact-top">
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY KEY&callback=initMap  type="text/javascript"></script>          
<div id="cd-google-map">
<div id="google-container"></div>
<div id="cd-zoom-in"></div>
<div id="cd-zoom-out"></div>
<address>7200 Polar Bear<br>San Antonio, Texas 78238</address> 
</div>  
<a href="#scroll-link" class="scroll scroll-down"></a>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Open it in a browser, Look at the console. 

Your API Keys have not been added. Also You should fix the other errors in the console as well.

Comment: The message indicating that your page "can't load Google Maps correctly" should include a link to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?utm_source=maps_js&utm_medium=degraded&utm_campaign=keyless#api-key-and-billing-errors) explaining the error message.